# Probability on roll of dice

Tags: probability

This question gave me some pause:

Suppose that you throw n dice. What is the probability that NO pair adds up to 8?

I know there are C(n,2) possible pairs. And these are all the possible ways of a pair adding up to 8:

2,6
3,5
4,4
5,3
6,2

So the probability of a pair adding up to 8 is 5/36. So the probability of a pair NOT adding up to 8 is 31/36 I guess?

From this how do we compute the probability that no pair adds up to 8? Do we just multiply C(n,2) * 31/36? I'm not sure that's right. Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

We want that among the $n$ die rolled, <s>none</s> *at most one* of them are four; two and six don't appear simultaneously; and likewise that three and five don't appear simultaneously.

[[Edit:  André Nicolas points out a modification needs to be made.]]

Let $X_i$ be the event that number $i$ never shows; $Y_i$ that it shows once.   To save typespace, let $X_i X_j$ be the conjunction of events.   (It is crowded even with that.)   What follows is as easy as PIE.   (That is the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.)

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(({X_4}\cup Y_4)({X_2}\cup{X_6})({X_3}\cup{X_5})) ~=~& {\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{X_4})+\mathsf P({X_3}{X_4}{X_6})+\mathsf P({X_2}{X_4}{X_5})+\mathsf P({X_4}{X_5}{X_6})\\-\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{X_4}{X_6})-\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{X_4}{X_5}) +\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{X_4}{X_5}{X_6})\\+\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{Y_4})+\mathsf P({X_3}{Y_4}{X_6})+\mathsf P({X_2}{Y_4}{X_5})+\mathsf P({Y_4}{X_5}{X_6})\\-\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{Y_4}{X_6})-\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{Y_4}{X_5}) +\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{Y_4}{X_5}{X_6})}
\end{align}$$

Note $\mathsf P({X_2}{X_3}{X_4})$ and so forth are each the probabilities that three specified numbers never show.   That is $(\tfrac {3}{6})^n$.   $\mathsf P(X_2X_3Y_4) = \tfrac n 6(\tfrac 36)^{n-1}$ And so on.

Put it together.

Comment: Good point! @AndréNicolas